# Why is this boolean slowing my simple scene down so badly? I'm using it as an 'Intersection' to see on this portion of an array passing through

Tags: animation, modifiers

Boolean shown in wireframe, allowing smaller rectangles (with array modifier active) to be seen as they pass through along the Y axis.  FPS is set to 30 but playback crawls at around 7fps. The boolean is definitely the culprit - when I deactivate it, playback is fine.  How can this simple modifier slow things down this much? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: can you please explain a bit more, what you want to achieve? Maybe a boolean modifier isn't necessary...

Comment: Hi Chris, I am trying to make an animation where only the section within the boolean will reveal the rectangles passing through.  I'm trying to build a stylized smart phone, showing screens passing by as they are scrolled through. I've seen this done online with no issue, so I'm not sure why this approach isn't working with my setup.

Comment: a boolean operation is not always that easy. It depends on the geometry which is used. And looks like in your case it must be calculated each frame. I asked because sometimes you can "hide" things with e.g. a plane or something else without using boolean modifiers. This would be much quicker.

Comment: Interesting. Can you briefly describe how you would hide something moving with a plane?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to cut out, but here is what i mean: [1]: setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txk8B.png -> if the camera is above it "sees" this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy5MP.png. And you could get the same result with a boolean modifier. It depends what you want to cut out. So *IF* you just want to cut-out something like a phone frame and render only the phone frame, this could be an alternative.

Comment: So what exactly is creating that gap in the blue plane? Is it another, unseen object?

Comment: Hello, try using the "Fast" solver, the "Exact" one is notoriously slow.

Comment: Ah yes! that totally worked - thank you so much, Gorgious!